# Firebase deploy command just hangs

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I'm new to Firebase and this is my first attempt to deploy a Vue app.

What I'm doing is

1. `'firebase init'` in my project directory, with the dist folder chosen as default (instead of public recommended in documentation)
2. `'firebase deploy'` in my project directory

So, nothing happens. In the firebase-debug.log I see there are some successful connections but then the process just hangs

```
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:20.680Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:20.683Z] Command:       C:\Users\---\scoop\apps\nodejs\current\node.exe C:\Users\---\scoop\apps\nodejs\current\bin\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase deploy
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:20.683Z] CLI Version:   3.18.4
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:20.683Z] Platform:      win32
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:20.683Z] Node Version:  v9.3.0
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:20.684Z] Time:          Mon Apr 23 2018 11:02:20 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (╨╖╨╕╨╝╨░))
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:20.684Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:20.694Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:20.694Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:20.696Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/my-project some - id  

 Mon Apr 23 2018 11:02:20 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (╨╖╨╕╨╝╨░))
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:21.666Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:21.667Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/my-project some - id/tokens  

 Mon Apr 23 2018 11:02:21 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (╨╖╨╕╨╝╨░))
[debug] [2018-04-23T08:02:22.906Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
```

Comment: How long did you wait?  Did you try a second time?

Comment: For ten minutes at least, maybe more, it is a pretty simple pwa to download. Do you think the server is just so busy?

Comment: I don't know.  You should contact Firebase support to diagnose. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: I have already contacted them. No answer, just a robot, asks more and more details. I'm starting suspect that it is my Russian origin is the cause though there are very few reports about the unavailability of the service in Russa and no one mention the deploy

Comment: I've installed a VPN, and everything is work now. It is sad that there where no any error messages to find the issue.